# Is there a way to delete all Facebook wall posts prior to a specified date?

Tags: facebook

I've just inherited a long-neglected Facebook page with a deep backlist of spam and unwanted wall posts, which engulf the front page. I don't want to hide the entire wall, because I'm posting new content, but it will be a while before the new stuff bumps the spam below the fold.

I know I can manually remove individual posts from the wall, but is there any way to delete posts in bulk, ideally before a specified date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, though it's a little convoluted.

First you need to have the person that is the admin of the page authorize your application and obtain the `manage_pages` extended permission. You'll probably also want the `publish_stream` and `offline_access` permissions.

Then you run the query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed
                        ?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
                        &since=UNIXTIMESTAMP
```

Where the UNIXTIMESTAMP is the time you went to get the posts up until. You can generate timestamps [here](http://www.timestampgenerator.com/).

You can then parse and grab all of the post ids and then run the query:

`https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?method=delete`

on each of the posts.

Alternatively you could use something like [iMacro](http://www.cynthiaperla.com/facebook/460/how-to-delete-all-groups-and-wall-posts-from-facebook-using-imacros.html) to just run a script on the page that will automatically delete all of the posts (though it would be difficult to stop at a particular date IMO).

Comment: For me this does only seem to work on posts which have been posted to the wall by the very same application that is trying to delete them :(

Comment: Thinking about it, I wrote a facebook app which is trying to achieve this, maybe I should just call the necessary html pages without an app, as if I'd be using a browser?

Comment: "Note that you can only delete the post if it was created by your app.".  Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts